# Nested If Statement to insert a link on picture with MVC Razor View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to insert a link on a Picture based in a condition:

The base code is:

```
@if(Model.PictureCount > 0) 
{
    <img src="@Model.PicturesPath@Model.Pictures[0].Filename" width="535" height="385" />
}
```

Now I need to insert a link around the picture if the id if XXX

```
@if(Model.PictureCount > 0)
{
    if(Model.Id == 18777)
    {
        <a target="_blank" href="XXXX">
    }
        <img src="@Model.PicturesPath@Model.Pictures[0].Filename" width="535" height="385" />
    if(Model.Id == 18777)  // <-- this If is not working has a C# condition
    {
        </a>
    }
}
```

The problem is that the second If condition is not working has a C# Code, it's just showing has html text.

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
@if(Model.PictureCount > 0)
{
    if(Model.Id == 18777)
    {
        @:<a target="_blank" href="XXXX">
    }
        <img src="@Model.PicturesPath@Model.Pictures[0].Filename" width="535" height="385" />
    if(Model.Id == 18777)  // <-- this If is not working has a C# condition
    {
        @:</a>
    }
}
```

Or this

```
@if(Model.PictureCount > 0)
{
    if(Model.Id == 18777)
    {
         @Html.Raw("<a target='_blank' href='XXXX'>")
    }
        <img src="@Model.PicturesPath@Model.Pictures[0].Filename" width="535" height="385" />
    if(Model.Id == 18777)  // <-- this If is not working has a C# condition
    {
        @Html.Raw("</a>");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks! I chose your first solution because it's simple and it respects the DRY rule

Answer (score 2):

```
@if(Model.PictureCount > 0)
{
    if(Model.Id == 18777)
    {
        <a target="_blank" href="XXXX">
        <img src="@Model.PicturesPath@Model.Pictures[0].Filename" width="535" height="385" />
        </a>
    }
    else 
    {
        <img src="@Model.PicturesPath@Model.Pictures[0].Filename" width="535" height="385" />
    }
}
```

Comment: why would you prefer not to?

Comment: Because of the DRY rule

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that Razor still requires valid balanced HTML tags. So you cannot open a tag in a conditional because within that conditional’s body the tag is not closed.

You basically have three options here:

1. Output raw text which happens to be HTML.

   You can either do that using the `Html.Raw` helper, or using the special raw Razor syntax `@:`. Both will allow you to output the opening and closing tags without it being valid for parsing:

   ```
   if (Model.Id == 18777)
   {
       @Html.Raw("<a target=\"_blank\" href=\"XXXX\">");
   }
   <img src="@Model.PicturesPath@Model.Pictures[0].Filename" width="535" height="385" />
   if (Model.Id == 18777)
   {
       @:</a>
   }
   ```
2. Have two cases which each have full and valid HTML code on their own. This requires you to repeat the content though:

   ```
   if (Model.Id == 18777)
   {
       <a target="_blank" href="XXXX">
           <img src="@Model.PicturesPath@Model.Pictures[0].Filename" width="535" height="385" />
       </a>
   }
   else
   {
       <img src="@Model.PicturesPath@Model.Pictures[0].Filename" width="535" height="385" />
   }
   ```
3. Choose a markup that allows you to avoid this problem completely. In this case, you could still wrap everything in a link but make that link non-functioning when your condition is not true:

   ```
   <a @{if (Model.Id == 18777) { <text>target="_blank" href="XXXX"</text> } }>
       <img src="@Model.PicturesPath@Model.Pictures[0].Filename" width="535" height="385" />
   </a>
   ```

   Of course this will not work in all situations, and might even break for links depending on styling that is applied to `a` tags (even without a link).

Comment: Hi thanks! I have chose the solution of @Dark Knight because is first option seems the me the most simple and he has been the first one to answer but thank you for your so detailed answer ;)

Comment: Sure thing :) Btw. you should know that *in addition* to [accepting one answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/141542), you can also upvote every helpful answer to the question as a sign of appreciation.